# Character & strings

Tags: haskell

I am new in haskell and I have a problem (aka homework).

So, I have a list with a tuple – a string and an integer:

```
xxs :: [([Char], Integer)]
```

I need to know how many of the strings in xxs start with a given character.
Let me exemplify:

```
foo 'A' [("Abc",12),("Axx",34),("Zab",56)]
Output: 2 

foo 'B' [("Abc",12),("Bxx",34),("Zab",56)]
Output: 1
```

My best attempt so far:

```
foo c xxs = length (foldl (\acc (x:xs) -> if x == c then c else x) [] xxs)
```

But, of course, there's something VERY wrong inside the lambda expression.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: You've got the right hunch. Check out the second parameter passed into your lambda; the way you have the pattern defined, Haskell expects a list. That would be fine if `xxs` is a list of lists, but it's only a list of tuples. Try a pattern like `(x,y)` instead, and see where that gets you. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your attempt:

1. You plan to use `foldl` to construct a shorter list and then to take its length. While it is possible, `filter` function is much better suited for that task as @landei suggests
2. `foldl` can be used to accumulate the length without constructing a shorter list. See the answer of @WuXingbo - his answer is incorrect, but once you realize that `length` is not needed at all with his approach, it should be easy for you to come with correct solution.
3. Somewhat contradictory to common sense, in a lazy language `foldr` is faster and uses less memory than `foldl`. You should ask your teacher why.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use a fold, but I would suggest another way, which breaks the problem in three steps:

- transform the input list to the list of first letters. You can use `map` for this
- `filter` out all elements not equal to the given `Char`
- take the `length` of the remaining list

Obviously the first step is the hardest, but not as hard as it looks. For doing it you just have to combine somehow the functions `fst` and `head`, or even easier, map twice.

You can write this as a simple one-liner, but maybe you should start with a `let`:

```
foo c xxs =  let strings = map ...
                 firstLetters = map ...
                 filteredLetters = filter ...
             in length ...
```

Comment: Steps 1 can be merged into step 2. Simply filter the list based on if the first letter of the String in the first part of the tuple is correct. This appears to be the approach that op is trying, by writing his own `filter` in terms of foldl.

Comment: That's correct, but you can see what happened when the TO tried to do too much steps at once :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite foo as

```
foo :: Char -> [(String, Int)] -> Int
foo c = length . filter ((==c).head.fst)
```

`fst` fetches the first element of a two-element tuple.

`(==c)` is a one-argument function that compares its input with `c` (see http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html paragraph 3.2.1 for better explanation).